# How to get an application to run every 30 minutes?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-15

I have an application that fetches some feeds. Is there a way I can get it to be done every 30 minutes?

(I've not installed a graphical desktop, so a terminal fix would be loveable :D)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use your `crontab`:

```
crontab -e
```

Then enter a line like the following

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/your/command
```

Save it and it should run every 30 minutes of every hour, every day.

<sub>Updated the 30 minutes part, was being too quick. Thanks @nicolas, you got a +1.</sub>

Comment: when i type crontab -e, am i suppose to open the file /tmp/crontab.DYFYJ1"?

Comment: Yes, this is normal behavior. The `crontab` command will take care of it. From the `manpage`: "After you exit from the editor, the modified crontab will be installed automatically."

Comment: is there a way to test crontab?

Comment: Call `crontab -l` to list your current crontab entries.

Comment: @Jason94: To test crontabs, I usually copy the entry and edit the time to run in the next minute.

Answer (score 7):

Cron sounds like what you're looking for.

Log in as the user you want the task to be ran by, then type "crontab -e"

Your favorite editor will open, and you will get a file with this format :

```
    # m h  dom mon dow   command
```

So to run '/home/foo/my_program' every 30min, you would add this line

```
    */30  *  * * * /home/foo/my_program > /dev/null
```

/dev/null is there so you do not get the output sent by mail if your program writes something to stdout.

Comment: By the way */30 means every 30 minutes while 30 means "every time the clock hits 30mins (0h30, 1h30, 2h30...) which would cause the task to be ran each HOUR instead of every 30 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cron` to run it periodically.

From the account of the user you wish to run the script:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add a new line as follows:

```
*/30 * * * *  <path/to/script>
```

Then save the crontab, which will automatically install it.  The job will then run every 30 minutes and email you any output.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds exactly like a job for cron. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) is a good howto use it, yes it's for ubuntu and you're using fedora, but as far as I'm aware there are no differences between the two regarding cron.